# Finite State Machine Implementation in an Entity Component System

Tags: oop, architecture, entity, state-machine

I would like to use a Finite State Machine to handle `Entity` states in my game. Specifically, for the purpose of this post, I'm going to refer to the `Player` entity.

My `Player` is going to have states such as idling, running, jumping, falling, etc... and needs some way to manage these states and the transitions between them. In an OOP environment, the simplest solution was to make each state its own class, and have a method called `handleInput` take in input and determine if a state change should occur. For example, in the `IdleState` if either move_right or move_left occurred, the state would change to a new `RunningState`. This is easy and makes sense because *the behavior of a state should be encapsulated in the state.*

However, everything changes when you use a FSM in an entity component system. States are no longer objects (because that would go against the flexibility of a component system), but are instead different arrangements of components. The `JumpState` might have components like `JumpComponent`, `AirbornMovementComponent`, etc... whereas the `AttackState` might have components to represent an attack like `SwingComponent`, `DamageComponent`, `SwordComponent`, etc... The idea is by rearranging the components, new states can be created. The systems job is to simply handle these components separately, because the systems don't care about the state, they only care about the individual components. The actual FSM sits in a `FSMComponent` held by the entity.

This makes a lot of sense, except for when it comes to handling state transitions. Right now I have an `InputSystem` that looks for Entities that have an `InputComponent` and a `FSMComponent` and attempts to update the state of the FSM based on the current input. However, this doesn't work so well.

The best way (in my opinion) for the FSM to handle input is to have each state determine how it wants to handle input and how to transition to a new state based on that input. This goes back to the OOP way of implementing a FSM, going against the design of an ECS where components are simply data bags and systems do all the logic. In an ECS, the idea would be to have a system handle state transitions, but that gets complicated because every FSM might have different conditions to transition between states.

You can't simply state in the `InputSystem` "if the input is to move right, then set the state to running". That would be specific to the player, but may not hold true for ***ALL*** entities. If one day I decide to make an enemy controllable, the inputs that work for a `Player` wouldn't be the same inputs for an `Enemy`.

**My question**: How can I let my FSM be generic enough and flexible enough in an ECS to allow for various implementations of state transitions without having to do explicit if/else checks in the systems themselves?

Am I approaching this completely the wrong way? If so, what's a better solution for implementing a FSM in an entity component system?

Comment: The ash framework has quite an interesting approach, there's a post where the author writes about it here: http://www.richardlord.net/blog/finite-state-machines-with-ash. He's also got source code available here: https://github.com/richardlord/Ash/tree/master/src/ash/fsm

Comment: I'm bumping up against a similar question. I need a FSM to manage my player's state, as they navigate into and out of different menus and modes. I think my approach will be pretty simple as it serves my needs -- a FSM component that defines the states and transitions, and any interested system will just examine it to determine if it should do anything. Much of the time the system will look at it and then do nothing. Wasteful, maybe, but simple and good enough for me. For now. I'd be really curious what you came up with. Swapping components on/off is too heavyweight for my needs.

Comment: @InfinitiesLoop i never ended up pulling out the FSM code, but here is my [project](https://github.com/scottbass47/meta-quest). The state machine code is under the `fsm` package (inside core/src/com/cpubrew/). To see how it's used, there are a lot of good examples in the `EntityFactory` inside the `factory` package (all entities in the game are built here). If you want a more in depth explanation of how it works I'd be happy to talk about it.

Answer (score 5):

Just riffing off of @fallaciousreasoning's post (and its subsequent comments).

Ash actually has two FSMs that operate at different levels.

First, there is the FSM operating at the Entity level that manages (entity) state transitions by changing the composition of components on an entity as you transition from one state to another.

And secondly there is the FSM operating at the Engine level that manages (engine) state transitions by changing the composition of Systems executed by the engine.

Combined they make for a pretty robust FSM.

The trick is to determine what type of transition you need to work with; one where 'data' composition drives transitions, or one where 'logic' composition drives transitions.

So armed with this new found knowledge lets reason about how this would work.

In more naive approaches to changing component composition, we'd use a number of 'tag' components, along with some lengthy switch statements (or if/else checks) to handle these changes in entity state, ultimately resulting in bloated Systems that do way more than they should. Ash's Entity FSM refines this and avoids those lengthy switch statements (or if/else clauses) by mapping a given component configuration to an identifier and providing a manager that can be used to trigger state transitions. This manager instance can be passed around as a property within a component OR it can be composed/injected as a member of a system.

Alternatively, taking the Engine FSM approach, we break out each bit of state specific logic into their own Systems, and swap them in and out based on the given (engine) state. This method is not without its drawbacks since the absence of a system will affect all entities associated with it. However, its not uncommon to have Systems dedicated to a single entity instance (for example, a player character) so this can prove useful in the right context. Come to think of it affecting entities globally via System swaps may be desirable in some cases as well.

( *Note: If the scope of your logic modification needs to be more narrow, you can restrict it to the System without involving the Engine FMS. This can be achieved by implementing the State pattern within a System where the system can change its behavior by delegating to different sub-systems based on state.*)

I've seen some ECS frameworks label System compositions as 'Phases', but they fundamentally act as FSMs where the ECS engine processes entities using different sets of systems associated with a given phase.

In closing, data composition is just one half of the equation; how you compose your bits (or blocks) of logic is just as important when trying to implement a FSM within an ECS.

Answer (score 0):

The ash framework has quite an interesting approach, the author writes about it [here](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/finite-state-machines-with-ash)

He takes a similar approach to the one you were suggesting, arguing that an entity's state is dependent on the components that make it up (which in turn, determine what systems process the entity).

To make managing the state transitions easier, he introduces a FiniteStateMachine class, which tracks what components are required for an entity to be in various states.

For example, an enemy AI might be in a patrol state if it has a `Transform` and `Patrol` component, so he would register that information with the FiniteStateMachine

```
 var fsm = new FiniteStateMachine(enemyEntity);

 fsm.CreateState("patrol")
    .WithComponent(new Transform())
    .WithComponent(new Patrol());
```

When the Finite State machine is told to change the state of the entity, it removes and adds components to get to the desired state. Any system that needs to change the state of the entity just needs a reference to the finite state machine (something like `fsm.ChangeState("patrol")`).

He's also released the source code for it, which you can find [here](https://github.com/richardlord/Ash/tree/master/src/ash/fsm) (it also explains it better than I ever could) and there's a practical example in the basic asteroids game [here](https://github.com/richardlord/Asteroids). The code is in ActionScript (I think) but you should be able to decipher it without too much difficulty.

Comment: This doesn't work well. Let me explain. What if you decide you want the player to run when the inputs for move left and move right are used. Then you could poll the input and change the state based on these values. Now, you decide you want to have a state where the player is frozen and can't move. All of a sudden, you're FSM breaks, because now you can run in a state where you're not supposed to run. Transitions are state specific and shouldn't be defined in the scope of a system.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't the run component be removed, which would stop the entity being processed by RunSystem, essentially freezing it? I'm just looking into this problem myself, as I've started developing my own ECS system, so I'm pretty far from an expert.

Comment: I've created a much more robust system that allows you to define transitions. Then I have transition systems that handle all entities in a state that has that transitions, and if the transition's requirements are met, the entity changes states.

Comment: @FaTalCubez Would you mind sharing your implementation? I'd love to see how you went about it in terms of code.

Comment: The code is too complicated to post here and its also incomplete. I'm working on abstracting it out more so its useful for more people, and then hopefully I can turn it into a library/extension for ashley.

Comment: @FaTalCubez You can throw it up on github or some other repo and leave a link here...

Comment: @FaTalCubez I'd be pretty interested in seeing it too